# What is the difference between CountVectorizer(binary=True) and n CountVectorizer(binary=False) in sklearn

Tags: python, vector, nlp, n-gram, countvectorizer

I run my script with defining ngram_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(binary=True) and ngram_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(binary=False)

The result of the confusion matrix is different for both. Could help me understand what binary do ?

Answer (score 2):

If you set `binary=True` then CountVectorizer no longer uses the counts of terms/tokens. If a token is present in a document, it is 1, if absent it is `0` regardless of its frequency of occurrence. So you will be dealing with just binary values. By default, `binary=False`.

See [usage examples here](https://kavita-ganesan.com/how-to-use-countvectorizer/#Ignore-Counts-and-Use-Binary-Values)